# I try to add simple java project to Deployment Assembly and it disappear

Tags: eclipse, web-deployment-project, eclipse-3.6

Hi stackoverflower,
I use eclipse `Helios` and this is my problem.

I have main project name `main`. It is Dynamic Web Project.
I have util project name `util`. It is Simple Java Project.

I open `Deployment Assembly` from `main` project.
I click Add -> Project -> choose `util` project-> Finish
In my screen show new project in table

```
Source : util | Deploy Path : /WEB-INF/lib/util.jar
```

Anything look good, I click OK.
But when I go to `Deployment Assembly` again `util` project disappear.
And sure that when I deploy, `util` project doesn't become jar file library.

Thanks for all suggestion.

Comment: Are you using Helios SR1 (3.6.1)? There was a lot of fixes on the Deployment Assembly front (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318068)

Comment: It works! I update eclipse and anything is ok. Big thanks @VonC !! :D

Comment: glad you made it work :) I have added that bug reference as an answer, for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo my comments above, I took notice of **[bug 318068](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318068) "Aggregate Deployment Assembly fixes for Helios SR1**", which includes *a lot* a bug fixes regarding that feature.

The OP [diewland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466693/diewland) reports:

> It works! I update eclipse and anything is ok.

So **[Eclipse3.6.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)** is recommended for "Deployment Assembly" operations.

Comment: eclipse indigo sr1 has the same problem, only solved in indigo sr2! Tks a lot!